# set the color of a blueprint div

Tags: blueprint-css

Is there a way to set the background colour of a div in blueprint?

I noticed that class=error will set the colour to pink (notify/success are similar):

```
<div class="error"> 
   <p>whatever</p>
</div>
```

But I want to know if there is a way to set the div to some arbitrary color?

EDIT: I don't actually care about error/notify/success. I just want to be able to set the color of a div in a similar way that they do, but using a color of my choice.

Answer (score 2):

Time to state the obvious - why can't you just override the `div.error` rule with your own?

`div.error { background:black; color:#fff; }` .. or are you not trying to break some sort of weird convention?  If so you can use a different classname.

Comment: Sorry I dont actually care anything about error, I was just using it as an example of a div that had a nice background color.

Answer (score 2):

Just... define your own CSS class and set the `background` and/or (for font color) `color` properties to color values; then set a div to have that as one of its classes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily over-ride the CSS by specifying a rule for `error` in your main CSS file.

That should ideally over-ride the default colors. Else, just ensure that you use a higher specificity in your rule, something like: `div.container div.error { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can set any color on this particular `div` by adding an `id` attribute:

```
<div class="error" id="myblueprint"> 
   <p>whatever</p>
</div>
```

Then add in your CSS file:

```
#myblueprint { background:blue; }
```